# Calculating cumulative sum for each row

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate the cumulative sum for each row using the following code:

```
df <- data.frame(count=1:10)

for (loop in (1:nrow(df)))
    {df[loop,"acc_sum"] <- sum(df[1:loop,"count"])}
```

But I don't like the explicit loop here, how can I modify it?

Comment: `help.search("cumulative sum")`

Comment: Do you mean to have a per row calculation?  If so, then your example `df` is only 1 column, which is easily handled with vector operations.  Try `df <- matrix(1:100, ncol = 10)` to generate a data frame based on a matrix (or, being pedantic, tensor of order 2).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You want `cumsum()`

```
df <- within(df, acc_sum <- cumsum(count))
```

Comment: +1 for within, wasn't aware of that one and can think of a number of uses! Cheers!

Comment: +1 I agree: `within` looks quite useful.  I'm surprised I've not seen it more.

Comment: Hmm, now I wonder if I'm missing something.  This seems to work for vectors as-is, but doesn't seem to work for a data frame with multiple columns.  However, it looks like `within` can be generalized for data frames with multiple columns.  Any ideas on that?  (E.g. `df <- matrix(1:100, ncol = 10)`)

Answer (score 15):

You can also try `mySum = t(apply(df, 1, cumsum))`.

The transpose is in there because the results come out transposed, for a reason I have not yet determined.

I'm sure there are fine solutions with `plyr`, such as `ddply` and multicore methods.

Comment: The first dimension in the result matches the length of individual calls to FUN, then the MARGIN dimension/s come next. So it's not so much "transposed" as that being only a trivial consequence in 2D. That's my reading of this in ?apply anyways. " If each call to ‘FUN’ returns a vector of length ‘n’, then ‘apply’ returns an array of dimension ‘c(n, dim(X)[MARGIN])’ if ‘n > 1’."

Comment: What's the benefit of calling apply here since `cumsum` is vectorized to begin with?

Comment: @Chase: I think you may be misreading the question.  Vectorization isn't relevant here.  The `apply` is necessary when the input is a data frame with both rows and columns > 1.  The OP has only given an example with a single column, so `cumsum` works as-is for that case, with no need for `apply`, but the title and text of the question refers to a per-row calculation.  Or am I misunderstanding you?  If you can get `cumsum` to work without specifying the margin via an external function, it would be good to know.

Comment: This has me wondering if there's an error in the original question.

Comment: Hmmm...well now I'm thoroughly confused as well :) I'll revisit this after some sleep and caffeine. As for per-row or per-column calculations, perhaps `colSums()` or `rowSums()` are more appropriate for the OP.

Comment: @mdsumner: that's correct.  I suppose I meant to say that the rationale (or necessity of coding this way) is irksome.  Although I've stopped using Matlab, I miss the ability to specify a matrix margin in calls to `sum` and `cumsum` (versus wrapping things in `apply`.  In R, `sum(myDF)` returns a single variable that is the sum of all of the values; in Matlab, this calculates a per-column sum.  Similarly for `cumsum` in Matlab.  Writing a `cumsum` along a specific margin in R is trivial, which is why I'd like it to be in base R.

Comment: @Chase: I'm in agreement about sleep.  :)  I think your approach is on the path to something more elegant.  It may be the case that `within` can give me joy that I cannot find in having to execute `t()`, `apply()`, and `cumsum()` in order to do a simple cumulative summation.  I also suspect now that the margin in `apply` should be `2`, if the OP is summing per column.  I need sleep before parsing the question again.

Answer (score 11):

To replicate the OP's result, the `cumsum` function is all that is needed, as Chase's answer shows.  However, the OP's wording "for each row" possibly indicates interest in the cumulative sums of a matrix or data frame.

For column-wise cumsums of a data.frame, interestingly, `cumsum` is again all one needs!  `cumsum` is a primitive that is part of the `Math` group of generic functions, which is defined for data frames as applying the function to each column; inside the code, it just does this : `x[] <- lapply(x, .Generic, ...)`.

```
> foo <- matrix(1:6, ncol=3)
> df <- data.frame(foo)
> df
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    5
[2,]    2    4    6
> cumsum(df)
  X1 X2 X3
1  1  3  5
2  3  7 11
```

Interestingly, `sum` is not part of `Math`, but part of the `Summary` group of generic functions; for data frames, this group first converts the data frame to a matrix and then calls the generic, so `sum` returns not column-wise sums but the overall sum:

```
> sum(df)
[1] 21
```

This discrepancy is (in my opinion) most likely because `cumsum` returns a matrix of the same size as the original, but `sum` would not.

For row-wise cumulative sums, there not a single function that replicates this behavior that I know of; Iterator's solution is probably one of the most straightforward.

If speed is an issue, it would be almost certainly be fastest and most foolproof to write it in C; however, it speeds up a little (~2x ?) for long loops by using a simple for loop.

```
rowCumSums <- function(x) {
  for(i in seq_len(dim(x)[1])) { x[i,] <- cumsum(x[i,]) }; x
}
colCumSums <- function(x) {
  for(i in seq_len(dim(x)[2])) { x[,i] <- cumsum(x[,i]) }; x
}
```

This can be sped up more by using the plain `cumsum` and subtracting off the sum so far when you get to the end of a column.  For row cumulative sums, one needs to transpose twice.

```
colCumSums2 <- function(x) {
  matrix(cumsum(rbind(x,-colSums(x))), ncol=ncol(x))[1:nrow(x),]
}
rowCumSums2 <- function(x) {
  t(colCumSums2(t(x)))
}
```

That's really a hack though.  Don't do it.

Answer (score 4):

With `data.table` you can also use

```
dt <- as.data.table(df)
dt[, acc_sum := cumsum(count)]
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to `cumsum()` could be:

```
within(df, acc_sum <- Reduce("+", count, accumulate = TRUE))

   count acc_sum
1      1       1
2      2       3
3      3       6
4      4      10
5      5      15
6      6      21
7      7      28
8      8      36
9      9      45
10    10      55
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
library(collapse)
dapply(df, MARGIN = 1, FUN = fcumsum)
```