# A CUMSUM in R with memory or window of two with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, cumsum

I am trying to aggregate data with a memory of 2, or memory of two rows.

Try the CUMSUM and Rolling function but without success.

This is an extract from the data:

```
data <-  data.frame( a = c(198030,152881,226933,173185,146450))

       a
1 198030
2 152881
3 226933
4 173185
5 146450
```

And I would like to get to the following:

```
       a      b
1 198030 198030
2 152881 350911
3 226934 577845
4 173185 751030
5 146450 897480
```

here column b is, for the first row, equal to column a, and for the other values, it is the sum of row a + the value before column b, and so on.

If it were in dplyr or tidyr better, but it does not matter so much.

Comment: Oscar, your expected output's column `a` is different (row 3) than what you created in the previous code block. (It took me a few minutes to figure out why I could not reproduce your numbers.)

Comment: Likely duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7550383/calculating-cumulative-sum-for-each-row

Answer (score 1):

I think `cumsum` is likely the best way (as has been demonstrated well in other answers). But your statement about *"sum of row a + the value before column b"* translated for me into a row's `b` value is equal to that row's `a` value plus `b`'s previous value. While `cumsum` does address this *much more efficiently*, the logic falls under `Reduce`:

```r
data$b <- cumsum(data$a)
data$b2 <- Reduce(`+`, data$a, init=0, accumulate=TRUE)[-1]
data
#        a      b     b2
# 1 198030 198030 198030
# 2 152881 350911 350911
# 3 226933 577844 577844
# 4 173185 751029 751029
# 5 146450 897479 897479
```

So if you really just need column `b` and all of your operations are simply `+`, then `cumsum` is best for you. If the problem was simplified/generalized a little and you need something a little more complicated that `cumsum` (etc) does not solve, then perhaps the premise of `Reduce(.)` is for you.

Comment: @akrun, there was no need to delete your question: yours was the first to recommend `cumsum`, and provides it in a `dplyr` method that the OP requested.

Comment: It's ok.  I deleted because it is likely to get dupe tagged.  Based on the current trend of acceptance by newbies, many won't even do it.  From a cost/benefit perspective, it is not worth it to keep it

Comment: I definitely understand the frustration (with n00b acceptance and such), but having it closed as dupe doesn't inherently detract points, yet deleting your question removed the upvote you had (not that you're starving for points). Thanks for coming back.

Answer (score 0):

cumsum should just work, but if u need to do something that
accumulates in a different way

```
> tibble( a = c(198030,152881,226933,173185,146450)) %>%
+ mutate(b=accumulate(a,~..2+..1))
# A tibble: 5 x 2
       a      b
   <dbl>  <dbl>
1 198030 198030
2 152881 350911
3 226933 577844
4 173185 751029
5 146450 897479
>
```